# Howto add a custom transformation java to java from Collection to Map

Tags: java, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

I want to transform an unmarshalled json as a *java to java* transformation. The primitive fields like Integer and String works. But I need to transform a list into a map and I want to do it with a converter like described in the guide, but I can't select `Add transformation` or `Add custom Transformation` in the mapping drop down menu. They are always lightgrey disabled.

I followed the *Fuse Transformation Tooling* guide and use eclipse photon and I installed the Jboss tools via the market place. I use the version `Red Hat Fuse Tooling Version: 11.0.0.v20180614-0309`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no support for custom converters in Fuse Tooling :-(.

```
Add transformation         # build-in transformation functions      
Add custom transformation  # custom transformation functions
```

These options are used for modification of formatting of particular values (for example: `String -> String`, apply *add brackets* custom transformation => `String -> "[" + String + "]"`. For more details see [GETTING STARTED WITH DATA TRANSFORMATION](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_fuse/7.0/html/tooling_user_guide/transtools#fuse_transformation_tooling) documentation.

You should be able to use Fuse Tooling Data Transformation tool to create an initial mapping between "primitive" fields and that directly modify `src/main/resources/transformation.xml` file and apply Dozer Custom Converters (see [Dozer - Custom Type Converters](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html))